# Private Docker Registry with Azure Storage and Nginx: 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: azure, nginx, docker

I am trying to run a private docker registry.

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name registry \
    -v /opt/registry/config.yml:/etc/docker/registry/config.yml \
    registry
```

config.yml:

```
version: 0.1
log:
  level: debug
storage:
  azure:
    accountname: ...
    accountkey: ...
    container: registry
```

afterwards the registry

```
docker logs -f registry
```

has the following output:

```
time="2017-02-21T16:29:45.584228329Z" level=warning msg="No HTTP secret provided - generated random secret. This may cause problems with uploads if multiple registries are behind a load-balancer. To provide a shared secret, fill in http.secret in the configuration file or set the REGISTRY_HTTP_SECRET environment variable." go.version=go1.7.3 instance.id=99dc49a2-d0c5-4d5f-8e2f-1b1ed77ec012 version=v2.6.0 
time="2017-02-21T16:29:45.584439534Z" level=info msg="redis not configured" go.version=go1.7.3 instance.id=99dc49a2-d0c5-4d5f-8e2f-1b1ed77ec012 version=v2.6.0 
time="2017-02-21T16:29:45.595020552Z" level=info msg="Starting upload purge in 10m0s" go.version=go1.7.3 instance.id=99dc49a2-d0c5-4d5f-8e2f-1b1ed77ec012 version=v2.6.0 
time="2017-02-21T16:29:45.623443737Z" level=info msg="listening on [::]:45908" go.version=go1.7.3 instance.id=99dc49a2-d0c5-4d5f-8e2f-1b1ed77ec012 version=v2.6.0 
time="2017-02-21T16:39:45.595199645Z" level=info msg="PurgeUploads starting: olderThan=2017-02-14 16:39:45.595164544 +0000 UTC, actuallyDelete=true" 
time="2017-02-21T16:39:45.641492799Z" level=debug msg="azure.List(\"/docker/registry/v2/repositories\")" go.version=go1.7.3 instance.id=99dc49a2-d0c5-4d5f-8e2f-1b1ed77ec012 trace.duration=46.132851ms trace.file="/go/src/github.com/docker/distribution/registry/storage/driver/base/base.go" trace.func="github.com/docker/distribution/registry/storage/driver/base.(*Base).List" trace.id=22a8eafa-43d4-4de4-9971-290cd9b12df6 trace.line=150 version=v2.6.0 
time="2017-02-21T16:39:45.641583901Z" level=info msg="Purge uploads finished.  Num deleted=0, num errors=1" 
time="2017-02-21T16:39:45.641605301Z" level=info msg="Starting upload purge in 24h0m0s" go.version=go1.7.3 instance.id=99dc49a2-d0c5-4d5f-8e2f-1b1ed77ec012 version=v2.6.0
```

nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name registry.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name registry.example.com;

    ssl_certificate      /opt/certificates/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /opt/certificates/privkey.pem;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  shared:SSL:10m;

    location / { 
        proxy_pass      http://localhost:5000/;
        proxy_redirect  default;

        proxy_set_header  Docker-Distribution-Api-Version registry/2.0;
        proxy_set_header  Host              $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_read_timeout   900;
        client_max_body_size 0;
    }
}
```

However I keep getting a '502 Bad Gateway' when I want to push an image to the registry, or when I go to https://registry.example.com

Answer (score -1):

- I would remove the http->https redirect as a first debugging step

```

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name registry.example.com;
   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

- Double check the registry path with `curl localhost:5000` command
- You would also need to update your proxy headers:

```

```
proxy_set_header  Host              $http_host;   # required for docker client's sake
proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr; # pass on real client's IP
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_read_timeout                  900;
```

- You should also consider adding auth headers to secure your registry

`auth_basic "Registry realm";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.htpasswd;`

Also I can see from the logs that your registry is running locally. Nginx throws `502` error when nginx-proxy target resource doesn't respond properly. You can also try `127.0.0.1:5000` under proxy pass. There is also a `docker-compose` way of doing port mapping on the following [link](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/nginx/).